# Join two tables by matching column values in SQL

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

Hi i have been trying to join two tables by their matching values.

I have my first table named location with the columns : (Country, State, City, Latitude, Longitude)

I have a second table named twitter with the columns : (User, Tweet, Latitude, Longitude)

What Im trying to do is join the location table to the twitter table that when the Latitude and Longitude match it will show the corresponding Country, State and City Columns next to the Twitter Data.

So far I have tried with no luck. All it does it add every city to every tweet in multiple rows.

```
select * from twitter
join location 
on twitter.latitude = location.latitude
and twitter.longitude = location.longitude
```

PLEASE HELP!

Comment: Your description suggests that the `latitude` values are the same in both tables, and the `longitude` as well.

Comment: Hi gordon, for instance lets say I have a tweet that has the lat and long of 50 and 100. In my list of coordinates 50 and 100 matches arizona. How can I make the table output arizona in connection with the tweet.

Comment: . . You need to provide sample data and desired results.  Your query looks correct.

Answer (score 2):

Since we may not have a location for every latitude/longitude, we use a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
select t.User
    ,t.Tweet
    ,t.Latitude
    ,t.Longitude
    ,l.Country
    ,l.State
    ,l.City
from twitter t
left join location l on t.latitude = l.latitude
    and t.longitude = l.longitude
```

Answer (score 0):

Use left join. It will give you all results.

```
select * from twitter
left join location 
on twitter.latitude = location.latitude
and twitter.longitude = location.longitude
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select * from twitter t
inner join location l
on t.latitude = l.latitude
WHERE t.longitude = l.longitude
```

Comment: Could you please [edit] in an explanation of why this code answers the question? Code-only answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148272/274165), because they don't teach the solution. (And in this case I'm reasonably certain the effect is the same as the posted code.)